# setTimeout doesn't seem to work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, settimeout

This setTimeout works perfectly in Firefox, but in Chrome nothing in function timeoutTrigger ever happens, including the alert. Any ideas?

```
var $this = $('.active-more');

function timeoutTrigger() {
    $this.closest(".container").nextAll(".container:first").find(".description:first").removeClass('hide');
    $this.closest(".container").nextAll(".container:first").find(".back:first").find("img.portfolio").remove();
    alert("is this thing on?");
}

setTimeout(function(){timeoutTrigger()},400)
```

Comment: Is the first 2 lines in `timeoutTrigger` causing some exception? Is there any error messages in console? the code seems correct.

Comment: +1 otakustay, this seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/sASvm/

Comment: Isn't `this` a keyword that shouldn't be used as a variable?

Comment: @MrXenotype : the variable is `$this`, not `this`

Comment: I'm very new to this and I'm using Dreamweaver. It finds no syntax errors and as I said it works in Firefox. I tried commenting out the first 2 lines in timeoutTrigger and the alert still doesn't occur. I can put the alert outside the setTimeout and it occurs so it's not that Chrome isn't using my latest js. So confused.

Comment: I'd suggest changing your variable name from `$this` to `$somethingelse`. `this` is a reserved word, Chrome may be interpreting your code differently than the other browsers. It may not be the issue, but when you get going with jQuery you'll be using `$(this)` type code and having variables called `$this` will be confusing.

Comment: @maskedjellybean : Any messages on `console` ?

Comment: In Chrome, Developer Tools is your friend -- either F12 or CTRL+Shift+I. Check the console for error messages.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, Bagavatu solved it. Wow it's always something small like that isn't it?

Comment: I will change the variable name and check out the Chrome console as well. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Switch your `setTimeout` statement to the following: `setTimeout(timeoutTrigger,400);`
The one you wrote is for when the function you're calling has a parameter. Also, you're missing a semicolon.

Comment: While good style advice, this doesn't really address the problem.

Comment: Also, strangely removing the () makes the setTimeout not work in Firefox.

Comment: The lack of a semicolon after `setTimeout(function(){timeoutTrigger()},400)` as Bagavatu pointed out.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. I left the () in and added the semicolon at the end and now it works in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Glad to see that it helped. Usually, some type of debugger like the Chrome Dev Tools Console or the Firebug Console in Firefox will catch these errors. But when in doubt, check that you have semicolons. :)

Comment: But timeout not working properly before time it open a window...Please tell me any another solution

Answer (score 0):

Google has changed the Content Security Policy which impacts using setTimeout() in some browsers.  Please read: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

Comment: At least add the impacts to your answer. e.g. setTimeout(string) will not execute with the default policy.

Answer (score 0):

We had trouble with settimeout function on Chrome. We wanted to run a API check in every 10 seconds to update page content if there is change in data. But although we set settimeout function to run in every 10 seconds, Chrome does not run it correctly if browser is inactive. (While Safari runs the code correctly even if it is inactive).

Our experiment shows that Chrome runs our function about minutely or a little longer when it is inactive. So checking updates minutely does not broke our code.

But we had second function which runs every minutes and changes content locally every minutes. To be specific, we change waiting times and play times of games which we are showing in the page content. So as we can not depend on Chrome to run at exact minutes, our solution is to save when the code is run first time, and check the minutes passed between dates, and change the waiting times and playing times accordingly.

```
     var $first_run_time; 
     var $minutes_passed = 0;
     var $total_minutes_used = 0;
     var $interval = 10000; // 10 seconds

     $current_date = new Date();
     $first_run_time = $current_date;
     console.log('Timeout started '+ $current_date.toLocaleTimeString());
     setTimeout(my_refresh_function, $interval));

    function my_refresh_function() {
            setTimeout(my_refresh_function, $interval);
            $current_date = new Date();
            console.log('Refresh run: ' + $current_date.toLocaleTimeString());
             $minutes_passed_from_start = Math.floor((Math.abs($current_date - $first_run_time)/1000)/60);

            $minutes_passed = $minutes_passed_from_start - $total_minutes_used;
  if ( $minutes_passed > 0 ) {
    
           // Make the changes you want for passed minutes
           // for example increase play time $play_time += $minutes_passed
           // and reduce waiting times $waiting_time -=  $minutes_passed
            console.log('Minutes updated +- '+ $minutes_passed + ' mins, at: ' + $current_date.toLocaleTimeString());

    $total_minutes_used += $minutes_passed;

      }
     }
```